# AppleScript intercept notifications

Tags: swift, macos, notifications, applescript, intercept

i'm having a look at AppleScript and notifications. I couldn't find too much on this topic which leaves me uncertain if it is possible to intercept notifications using AppleScript.

Id like to write an app on Mac OS that intercepts all incoming notifications and displays it in a window. It seems like the only way possible would be using AppleScript.

Is it possible to achieve this using AppleScript, or should I be looking at something else?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: It's not possible with AppleScript.

It's not even possible with Objective-C/Swift unless you are talking about the *Cocoa Distributed Notifications*